# Componente vue mask só é aplicado ao mexer no campo

Tags: vue.js, mask, vuetify

Estou aprendendo usar `vue` e `vuetify` e estou utilizando uma biblioteca, para fazer campos com máscara.

A bicicleta em questão é vue-mask.

Ao carregar o componente, a máscara não é aplicada automaticamente, a não ser que eu mexa no campo, ou digite algo novamente.

```js
<v-text-field
    v-model="item.phone"
    v-mask="'(##) #####-####'"
    label="Telefone"
/>
```

Exporto o componente de forma global.

```js
import VueTheMask from 'vue-the-mask';
Vue.use(VueTheMask)
```

Alguém sabe como resolver isso?

Comment: Esse componente funciona assim, tem esse componente que pode te ajudar [Vue Masked Input](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-masked-input) e nos seus [exemplos fica claro como utilizar](https://niksmr.github.io/vue-masked-input/)

Answer (score 2):

como diretiva, o mask do VueTheMask é chamado por `mask=""`.. além disso, nao tem porque usar aspas e depois aspas simples dentro.. coloque dessa forma no componente: `mask="(##) #####-####"`

Answer (score 0):

Isso funcionará como você espera

```
<v-text-field
   v-model="item.phone"
   :value="item.phone.toString()"
   v-mask="'(##) #####-####'"
   label="Telefone"
/>
```

Answer (score -3):

tive o mesmo problema tentando setar o valor do campo no mounted. Troquei pelo created e funcionou.